# apps script trigger interval difference

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-docs

I have my organizational alert system where I need to check every hour against the given list of dates,

A date is often compared against the current trigger and processed if they (current date - a date in the list) match closer, i.e. difference is less than 60 then it means process otherwise wait for another hour.

Only allowed to create a single trigger/doc/user.

Now the question is since triggers run +-15 min, what should be value of the difference? to as I can pass all 24 without a miss.

I have chosen 60, is it right? or 45 min or 75 min ?

Comment: If you want to be safe  and not double-notify you can keep a log of what has been processed in the spreadsheet or the cache.

Comment: any techniques by using cache?

Comment: you can just store the dates as keys and and true as the value. You can then lookup the value in the dictionary, if it is truthy you already processed it and can skip it